# Signing a hash using MSVC++

Tags: visual-c++, cryptography, hash, public-key-encryption

My program which is written in MSVC++  need to sign a hash. I've found an example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Can any one please tell how can i use my custom private key to sign the hash. In the example i could not see it accepting a user defined key/text.

Also, please tell me if it is good to store a public key in a text file.

Thank you,
John

Comment: It uses the current user's default signing key from their key store. Do you want to just use one key, i.e. can you just put your key in the store, or do you need to change the key for each signature? Pass parameters to `CryptAcquireContext` to select a different key, but I think it has to still be from the system key store.

Answer (score 1):

Within the [Example C Program: Encrypting a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382358%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) session key derived from a password is used to encrypt data. Of course you have to know the password otherwise you can not be sure who decrypted (or signed in your case).

It's mandatory to make the public part of the key available to *everyone* otherwise verifying the signature is not possible to someone else. A text file is also ok.